# Absolute values and a square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a question about square roots, which I can't remember. If we have a square root of $\sqrt{(x - c)^2}$ then taking it to the 2nd power yields $|x - c|$. If we have a square root of $\sqrt{(x - c)^2 + (y - d)^2}$ then second power of it yields $(x - c)^2 + (y - d)^2$. Do I remember it correctly?

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-c)^2}$ itself is $| x-c |$. When you take it to the second power, you get $(x-c)^2$ back.

Comment: For the first one, raising to the second power yields $(x-c)^2$.

Comment: And second one is without absolute value?

Comment: You don't need the absolute value for the second case, because $(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2 \ge 0$ already.

Comment: Note: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, but $(\sqrt x)^2 = x$ because $x\ge 0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{M}$ implies, if this expression is valid, that $M \ge 0$.  Taking it to the second power $\sqrt{M}^2 = M$.  You don't need absolute value because it was assumed $M \ge 0$.  so $\sqrt{(x-c)^2}^2 = (x-c)^2$ and $\sqrt{(x-c)^2 +(y -d)^2}^2 = (x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2$.  HOWEVER.  If M can be post or neg $M^2 \ge 0$, then $\sqrt{M^2} = |M|$ and the absolute value signs *are* nescessary.  Do you see the difference between $\sqrt{M^2} = |M|$ and $\sqrt{M}^2= M$ and why one needs abs value signs and the other doesn't?